# Как асинхронно скачать файлы? [Android - Java]

Tags: java, android, download

Всем привет! Необходимо скачать файл по имеющейся ссылке и сохранить по указанному пути. 
Путь указать несложно, скачать файл, относительно, тоже. Но вот возникла проблема с асинхронностью.
Предположим, я захожу в activity, где при старте начинают скачиваться 3 файла. Как сделать параллельное скачивание?
А так же, есть ли возможность отображать процесс загрузки, например, в процентах?

Comment: Я так понял, загрузку файла вы уже реализовали? Как? Просто известные мне способы не должны были создать проблем с получением процента загрузки. Асинхронность тоже зависит от способа загрузки и размеров файлов, она может оказаться просто ненужной. Потому добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию о том как скачиваете файл, их размер и применение

Comment: создавать отдельные потоки под каждую загрузку (RxJava, concurrency, callback)

Comment: DownloadManager?